# TypeError in JQuery. Doesn't substring url

Tags: jquery

I have Url: 'http://domain.com/sites/pages/Detail.aspx?id=1'.

I need, that function return 'EventDetail.aspx?ids=1'.

I have next function:

```
function getFullPageName(url) 
{
    var index = url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
    var filenameWithExtension = url.substr(index);
    return filenameWithExtension;                                   
}
```

But, when I call like this:

```
var fullName=getFullPageName(window.location);
```

I see in firebug error:

```
TypeError: url.lastIndexOf is not a function
var index = url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
```

So. How its' fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) is an object, not a string so the method `lastIndexOf` is not present in the `window.location` object. You can use the `href` property of `window.location` instead.

```
var fullName=getFullPageName(window.location.href);
```